# 180 first characters of a string ending with a word

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to shorten a string down..

Lets say we have a string with the length 500.

I only want the first part of it - **max 180 characters**, ending with the **last word** before reaching the 180. I don't want to cut the string short in the middle of a word.

How is this achived? it does not have to perform all that well.. it is something that happens a couple of times a day, not more.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A really easy way is by using this regex:

```
string trimmed = Regex.Match(input,@"^.{1,180}\b").Value;
```

The only problem with that one is that it could contain trailing whitespace. To fix that, we can add a little negative look-behind:

```
string trimmed = Regex.Match(input,@"^.{1,180}\b(?<!\s)").Value;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: you wrote 18 instead of 180 in your second expression, which works perfectly btw :)

Answer (score 3):

How about looking at char 180, and move backwards to find the first char in (lets say space, comma, exclamation etc) indicating the start of the previous word?

Comment: Why use iterative processing when there are built in tools to find what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

*Conceptially*

Check that the string is over 180 characters long.

Grab the first 180 characters as a substring.

Return what you need by using the "LastIndexOf" method to get the length of the string combined with a substring to return the appropriate string.

**In Code:**

```
        string InString;

        InString = "Your long string goes here";

        if (InString.Length>180) //Check the string length
        {
            InString = InString.Substring(0, 180); //Get the first 180 chars
            InString = InString.Substring(0,InString.LastIndexOf(" ")); //Stop at the last space
        }
```

This should return the correct string; though LastIndexOfAny will allow you ta add other characters to your EOL list.

Answer (score 0):

You just use the normal commands on string class:

```
string short = myStr.Substring(0, 180);
int end = short.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] {' ', '\t', '\n'}); //maybe more
return short.Substring(0, end);
```

Comment: I think you meant to use the LastIndexOfAny method - in this way you only include the first word.